# Chef not deleting files in %systemroot%\system32 path using file resource

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, chef

I am using chef [`file`](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_file.html) resource for deleting files inside `%systemroot%\system32` path in Windows machine. Resource block is as below,

```
file 'Delete_File' do
  path 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\my.dll'
  action :delete
end
```

I had ensured that Windows service which uses this `dll` is stopped before calling `file` resource block.

But still file is not deleted at the end of `chef-client` run. So, I am assuming some access permission settings to be done for this to work.

Any pointer will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you're using a 32-bit build of `chef-client` on W2K8R2, which is an x64 architecture OS. Asusming that's the case the directory your `chef-client` process "sees" as `%systemroot%\system32` is actually `%systemroot%\syswow64`. I would guess your DLL isn't in there to be deleted.

This [has been discussed in a ticket at Opscode](https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-4726) and the workaround described there, referencing the `%systemroot%\sysnative` notation is probably the best thing you can do.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have used `Sysnative` instead of `system32` and worked. After changing to `Sysnative` got `EACCES` error and so added attribute `atomic_update false` to `file` resource. Please refer [here](https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-4625) for more details.